# why dynamic component that creates itself propgate information to parent components?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I have a simple weather app that as a user I need to choose between two cities (Tel Aviv or Kyiv), choose which units I wish to see the weather (imperial, metric or standard) and display the result from the openweather rest api.
When I click on the plus button I need to create the same component again and continue the same functionality.

I use ngrx to handle the states of this app, and also using the weahter api from this website:
https://openweathermap.org/current#data

Now that we understand what was needed from me, I did everything pretty good but I have a bug that when I create the new child components, the details that I display bubbles/overwrite my previous data for every previous/parent component.

I uploaded the code to stackblitz here:

for editing: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-weather-app?

for just running: https://github-weather-app.stackblitz.io

so the main question is: when I create a component using dynamicFactoryResolver with the same component, why does the information that I need to display propgate to the parent component that created it?

Thanks

EDIT: I fixed the code to return dummy information instead of using the http get method just to demo my real problem with ngrx

Comment: `nothing out of those solutions worked for me so I need the hive mind help` sorry but that is not how [so] operates. Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic)

Comment: Hi igor thatnks. I fixed the question hope people will know how to help me

Comment: I cannot run your stackblitz at all, in two different browsers its unable to load the source map, so I cannot check the code. But the issue as you describe it seems to be store related. Are you updating the store coming from each child component? Sounds like a change in a single child component (e.g. the Unit) is propagated to all child components via the store.
The store is a singleton, it lives only once in your application.

Comment: Hi Loop thanks for the answer. yeah the stackblitz is making some problems it can't reach the rest api since it is not https :S but the rest of the logic should work.

Anyway you are right I think it is the store, no I'm not updating the store should I create for every child component a new store then which will be specific to every unit?

I can't do anything about the propgation due to the way the store work as a singleton?

let me know if you have some other ides that I should try and check :)

Comment: I would try storing each component value in some sort of collection/array. Could you try returning some dummy data instead of actually doing a http call in your stackblitz?

Comment: Hi Loop sorry it took me a while : yeah I fixed it and updated the links I hope you can help me now that my service returns a dummy random json result (tel aviv or kyiv weather)

this is the link for editing the code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-weather-app?

and this is for see the results without edit:
https://github-weather-app.stackblitz.io